# Undeletable file in Linux Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, emacs

So there's this file in my $HOME I found recently called #fibonacci.js#

I attempted to remove it using the rm -f method and even though the command went through, it's still there. Does anyone have any ideas on how to remove it and what is it exactly?

Also, I recently installed emacs and tried editing the original file, fibonacci.js, and closed emacs. I also tried deleting fibonacci.js, but the #fibonacci.js# still remains.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: With what *exact* command did you try to remove `#fibonacci.js#` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file `#fibionacci.js#` is an automatic back-up of the edition, with `emacs`, of file `fibionacci.js`.

So you edited with `emacs` that file, but you forgot to save it (under Emacs). If you would edit with `emacs` that same file, it would ask you if you want to recover the saved snapshot.

You can remove it with e.g. the `rm -v "#fibionacci.js#"` command or with `rm -vf \#fibionacci.js\#`. (You may need to quote the file name for your shell because `#` may have a special meaning to your shell; you could also escape the `#` with a backslash before).

You could also remove all files named `*.js*` interactively with `rm -i ./*.js*` (and the `rm` command would ask you, for every match, if you want to remove that file; answer `y` if you do want to remove it).

BTW, the `rm` command has a lot of options, type `rm --help` or read its manual page [rm(1)](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_rm.htm) which you can also get by typing `man rm` (try also `info rm` since `rm` is a GNU utility on Linux). You'll better first learn how to use the `man` command, e.g. with `man man`....

<sup>PS: your file is not undeletable (you'll need to use `chattr +i` to make a file nearly undeletable). It has just a weird name, so you need to escape that name to be understood by the shell...</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot! So emacs always saves an edited version even when you exit emacs. I /do/ remember being asked whether I wanted to save the file or not after I edited and was about to exit, but I selected no...